# Which is correct : Open one Connection for inserting List of objects or open connection for every single insertion?

Tags: c#, performance, design-patterns, asp.net, informix

I have written the following method twice but I don't know which is better from performance perspective, code design and best practice.

> **First:**

```
public int Insert()
        {
            int affectedRow = -1;
            using (IfxConnection con = new IfxConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sh"].ToString()))
            {

                StringBuilder cmdTxt = new StringBuilder();
                cmdTxt.Append(" INSERT INTO shedule(day,short,name,depcode,studycode,batchnum) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
                using (var myIfxCmd = new IfxCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con))
                {
                    myIfxCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("day", IfxType.Char);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("short", IfxType.NVarChar);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("name", IfxType.NVarChar);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("depcode", IfxType.Integer);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("studycode", IfxType.Integer);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("batchnum", IfxType.Integer);

                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }

                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[0].Value = ((object)this.DayId) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value = ((object)this.ShortName) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[2].Value = ((object)this.Name) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[3].Value = this.DepCode;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[4].Value = this.StudyCode;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[5].Value = this.BatchNum;

                    affectedRow = myIfxCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            return affectedRow;
        }
```

**THEN :**

```
   foreach (Day a in days)
    {
        affectedRow = a.Insert();
    }
```

---

> **Second:**

```
public int Insert(List<Day> days)
        {
            int affectedRow = -1;
            using (IfxConnection con = new IfxConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sh"].ToString()))
            {

                StringBuilder cmdTxt = new StringBuilder();
                cmdTxt.Append(" INSERT INTO shedule(day,short,name,depcode,studycode,batchnum) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
                using (var myIfxCmd = new IfxCommand(cmdTxt.ToString(), con))
                {
                    myIfxCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("day", IfxType.Char);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("short", IfxType.NVarChar);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("name", IfxType.NVarChar);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("depcode", IfxType.Integer);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("studycode", IfxType.Integer);
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("batchnum", IfxType.Integer);

                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    foreach (Day a in days)
                    {
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[0].Value = ((object)a.DayId) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value = ((object)a.ShortName) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[2].Value = ((object)a.Name) ?? DBNull.Value;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[3].Value = a.DepCode;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[4].Value = a.StudyCode;
                        myIfxCmd.Parameters[5].Value = a.BatchNum;

                        affectedRow = myIfxCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

            }

            return affectedRow;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the best is to do all your inserts in one connection.

Open/Close a connection implies a penalty. Although it is mitigated by some connection pooling mechanism on the database side (btw what is it ?), it is additional work that is not useful nor required.

The reason is that there is the possibility to use a Transaction to ensure that "all or nothing" is inserted, regarding whether things goes good or bad in your insertion loop, and *in most cases* a transaction is tied to a connection.

Here is something that includes a transaction. That'the way I am doing it in SQLServer. I assumed that the Informix transaction are correctly implemented using the ADO.NET scheme, and I do not know is this implementation is working.

---

```
public int Insert(List<Day> days)
{
    int affectedRow = -1;
    using (IfxConnection con = new IfxConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sh"].ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        using(var transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var cmdTxt = " INSERT INTO shedule(day,short,name,depcode,studycode,batchnum) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
            using (var myIfxCmd = new IfxCommand(cmdTxt, con,transaction ))
            {
                myIfxCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("day", IfxType.Char);
                myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("short", IfxType.NVarChar);
                myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("name", IfxType.NVarChar);
                myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("depcode", IfxType.Integer);
                myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("studycode", IfxType.Integer);
                myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("batchnum", IfxType.Integer);



                foreach (Day a in days)
                {
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[0].Value = ((object)a.DayId) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value = ((object)a.ShortName) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[2].Value = ((object)a.Name) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[3].Value = a.DepCode;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[4].Value = a.StudyCode;
                    myIfxCmd.Parameters[5].Value = a.BatchNum;

                    affectedRow = myIfxCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            // commit the changes in the database. 
            // if an exception occurs somewhere, then the using blocks
            // makes that the transaction is disposed and rolled back,
            // and nothing will be updated in the database
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    return affectedRow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot ,Could you refactor my code with transaction and the notes you think it's useful please?

Comment: Ok, gimme just an hour left and I will do that.

Comment: i will be grateful ,my DB is `informix` :)

Comment: Well I removed the StringBuilder. It is not worth using a StringBuilder that way, because there is no massive string concatenations.

Comment: i test the method , edit it . thanks a lot .Do i need to convert it to static method

Comment: I don't see why not :)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you employ a `StringBuilder` when you don't do anything with it? Especially when you *should* be using it. Right now the names of the various fields are defined in two places:

```
mdTxt.Append(" INSERT INTO shedule(day,short,name,depcode,studycode,batchnum) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
```

And also:

```
myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("day", IfxType.Char);
myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("short", IfxType.NVarChar);
```

If one of them changes, you now have to change its name in two places, which is a recipe for disaster.

Also note that `shedule` contains a typo, it should be `schedule`.)

---

This is another accident waiting to happen:

```
myIfxCmd.Parameters[0].Value = ((object)this.DayId) ?? DBNull.Value;
myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value = ((object)this.ShortName) ?? DBNull.Value;
myIfxCmd.Parameters[2].Value = ((object)this.Name) ?? DBNull.Value;
myIfxCmd.Parameters[3].Value = this.DepCode;
myIfxCmd.Parameters[4].Value = this.StudyCode;
myIfxCmd.Parameters[5].Value = this.BatchNum;
```

What if the order changes? Also, this makes it hard to figure out which parameter is connected to which field.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, [this is the way OleDb is working in ADO.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828368/c-sharp-sql-server-parameters-and-oledb). Parameters are ordered and do not care about names. I know, it is a pain in the a**.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but you don't answer the original question .Could you refactor the method in the way you did think it will be more better to use .

Comment: @Larry True, but that still doesn't change the fact that it can be done a lot better.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare A code review can be about all aspects of the code, and I am not necessarily obliged to answer the question. I don't have the time for a refactor, unfortunately.

Comment: Too bad. I am very interested to see some code to circumvent that params order thing in ADO.NET I'm p****d at so often.

Comment: Your comment about names is simply not true, as the field names and the parameter names are not tied together and could be different.  A code review should be about the aspects of the code that you understand

Comment: @edc65 From what I gather the parameter name does seem to be completely useless yet required. In the code the parameter and the field name correspond (not a bad idea), so it would be good to ensure they actually stay coupled.